# Asus TUF Gaming FX505-DD - problem with wireless interface

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, asus, lts

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and my kernel version is 5.0.0-31-generic. I've installed Ubuntu three days ago.

I successfully installed the `rtl8221ce` driver from [this git repo](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) for my RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter. I even used the WiFi interface for a few days.

But, sometimes, Ubuntu does not recognize that I have this interface. It does not even show when using `lspci | grep less`. So, I turn off the computer for about 5 minutes and power it on again, resulting in some times recognizing it and some not.

I'm starting to think this might be a hardware issue, but before jumping to conclusions I would like to know your opinions. Maybe there is something I have not taken into account.

**TL;DR:** WiFi interface is sometimes not recognized by the system, but after a few reboots it is fixed magically without doing anything else. Please, tell me there's a chance this is not a hardware issue. What is your opinion?

**PS:** Ubuntu is not installed using UEFI and Secure Boot is disabled on BIOS.

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Answer (score 0):

Installing a newer kernel version by command:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```