# Problem recognising RTL8821CE Wifi Card Driver (Asus TUF FX505DT)

Tags: networking

I have recently dual booted a Ubuntu 19.04 OS and Windows 10 in my laptop.

On the Windows, the drivers are perfect, but majority of my work is done in Ubuntu (OS building and ML).

The Wifi card (RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter) inside this laptop is very new and there is no opensource linux driver support for it online.

I have tried [this](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) option but the driver is still being shown as Unclaimed by the `lshw` command

PS I have already referred to all the questions related to TUF-FX505 driver issues for 16.04 and 18.04 on this forum.
[Asus TUF Gaming FX505-DD - problem with wireless interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180220/asus-tuf-gaming-fx505-dd-problem-with-wireless-interface/1192170#1192170)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo dkms status` and also: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and finally: `sudo modprobe rtl8821ce`

Comment: Thanks, the issue got sorted after I added the third part linux driver for rtl8821 and installed it.